# Send wav files through form

Tags: php, html, file-upload, wav

I am currently experiencing a weird problem on my website.
I have a form meant to send some text and files.

The issue is that, as soon as one of the files is a .wav file, the action page does not receve anything : $_POST and $_FILES are empty…

It works fine with mp3 or png files, so I don't understand…

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the size of that file ? compare it to your .mp3 and try to upload something that has the same size as your .mp3 file. If you can upload that then check your php.ini and change the following values to your desired limit:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 10M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 10M
```

Comment: Indeed, it was the issue ! Thanks a lot ! I didn't pay attention to file size.